# Полный вывод информации о сборке при использовании NDK через Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android, android-ndk

Я собираю проект под Android NDK в Eclipse через отдельный сборщик.

```
-> Project/Properties/Builders/...
```

Как сделать так, чтобы сборщик выводил развернутую информацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В свойствах билдера `Eclipse` надо задать аргумент для `ndk-build` `V=1`.